# Not able to access Einstein bot on Community

Tags: community, einstein

I have created an Einstein Bot. Its preview works as expected in Bot Builder.

Then I have added it to Community as Embedded Service Deployment. It was added but my main goal is to make it work even if no agents are online (with offline support disabled).

I can see an option in Bot Builder that agent is not required.
[image]

But still in Community on the preview I see:

[image]

And I can't start a dialog with bot.

May be I miss some additional setting, please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the approach mentioned in https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lag3QAA which is to Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts in the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is described in the article below.

https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lag3QAA

Answer (score 0):

Copying the solution posted in [link](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lag3QAA) for better visibility as links tend to expire over time.

1. Remove previously entered Chat specific JS code from Head Markup (Go to Builder settings > Advanced > Edit Head Markup)
2. Change Script Security Level to 'Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts' (Go to Builder settings > Security > Content Security Policy (CSP))
3. Add Chat Site URL (url which shows in error something like https ://d.*.salesforceliveagent.com) to Trusted Sites for Scripts (Go to Builder settings > Security > Trusted Sites for Scripts)